# How to set up a string array with strings that would display through the array on a text for iphone?

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, arrays

I'm new to iphone development but I have done android before. The following is something I have done in java and I want to convert this over to iphone.

```
 public class RelationshipTipsActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

String facts[] = {"Coming soon",
        "Coming soon", };

TextView display, display1;
TextView counter;
Button begin;
Button next;
Button previous;
Button random;
Random myRandom;

int index = facts.length;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(starting.rt.R.layout.relationship);

    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    display1 = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Begin);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.tvResults);
    counter = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.tvCounter);
    next = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Next);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Previous);
    random = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Random);

    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    random.setOnClickListener(this);
    // display.setOnTouchListener(this.gestureListener);
    myRandom = new Random();

    // gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    // gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    // public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // }

    // };
}



private void showDisplay() {
    display.setText(facts[index]);
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1) + "/"
            + String.valueOf(facts.length));
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case starting.rt.R.id.Next:
        index++;
        if (index > facts.length - 1) {
            index = 0;
        }
        showDisplay();

        break;

    case starting.rt.R.id.Previous:
        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = facts.length - 1;
        }
        showDisplay();
        break;

    case starting.rt.R.id.Random:
        index = (myRandom.nextInt(facts.length) - 1);
        if (index < 0) {
            index = facts.length - 1;
        }
        showDisplay();
        break;

    }

}
```

}

How would you convert something along the lines of that code from android to iphone.

I have this code so far for iphone, I just don't know where to go from there.

```
(IBAction) clicked:(id)sender{
NSArray *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
//NSString *newLabelText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", titleOfButton];
NSArray *initializedNSArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"red", 
                               @"blue", 
                               @"green", 
                               @"yellow", 
                               nil];
labelsText.text = initializedNSArray;
[initializedNSArray release];
```

}

I want to be able to display those strings within the Iphone View. And be able to click a next or previous button to go to the next or previous string which could be from blue to red or red to blue. Basically if there are any tutorials out there that help me with that or if you know how to help I would appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a `int` variable with the current position of the string from the array and two methods `goPrev` - `goNext` that increments and decrements the `int` variable.

In the interface:

```
UIButton *btn;
int step;
NSArray *titles;
```

And in the implementation:

```
-(void)setup {
titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title 1",@"Title 2",@"Title 3",@"Title 4", nil];
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
}

-(void)goPrev {
if (step>0) {
    step--;
}
[btn setTitle:[titles objectAtIndex:step] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)goNext {
if (step<titles.count-1) {
    step++;
}
[btn setTitle:[titles objectAtIndex:step] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: How exactly would you put everything in the class?

Comment: @JacobBrans I just showed you the `previous` and `next` methods.